# Unable to Write to Android Removable Storage in Python

Tags: python, android, permissions, storage

So let me start by telling you what works...

in the Buildozer Spec File I have:
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, INTERNET

and in my code I have:
from android.permissions import request_permissions
from android.permissions import Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

When I run the app for the first time it asks me (as a user) to grant permission to access storage.

On the Samsung Tablet I'm running AndroidOS 7.1.1
I can now create Folders on the INTERNAL memory and copy files to the Internal Memory (which is also referred to as external sd memory also for some reason.)  But I can NOT create a folder on my removable SD card. Why?

Same on my Amazon Fire Tablet HD10 9thGen running FireOS 7.3.1.6

But on my Phone running AndroidOS 10.0 I am unable to create a folder or write files to any directory outside of my private app related folder in the root directory that I don't have access to.  But I think I know why.  Because of the new rules.  Which I still haven't figured out yet how to grant permissions yet.

But I think first I would like to solve the problem of why I can write to my internal sd memory on AndroidOS 7.1.1 after permission is granted but WHY I am denied the ability to write to the removable sd memory.  Like I stated above all permissions have been coded and granted. So what am I missing?

Comment: Removable micro sd cards are read only since Android 4 about. But there is one app specific directory where you can write to. Have a look at the second one item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: For an Android 10 device request legacy external storage in manifest and it will behave like before 10.