# I can't read/write on the external memory of my Galaxy A41

Tags: android

With Android studio, I installed this example on my smartphone.

At the first launch I have a message asking me if I allow the application to have access to the external memory. I answered yes.

On the second launch (or subsequent ones), using the debugger, I notice that the permission is granted and continuing the code, but when I reach the line:

> FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

it goes directly to:

> } catch (Exception e) {

While I have permission, it doesn't work.

Doing the same manipulation, but using "run" instead of "debug", I get the following error (logcat):

> 2020-11-28 11:05:25.135 16779-16779/com.example.testrw D/path:
> /storage/emulated/0/UniqueFileName.jpg 2020-11-28 11:05:25.135
> 16779-16779/com.example.testrw W/System.err:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/UniqueFileName.jpg:
> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 2020-11-28 11:05:25.135
> 16779-16779/com.example.testrw W/System.err:     at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496) 2020-11-28 11:05:25.136
> 16779-16779/com.example.testrw W/System.err:     at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:235) 2020-11-28
> 11:05:25.136 16779-16779/com.example.testrw W/System.err:     at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:186) 2020-11-28
> 11:05:25.136 16779-16779/com.example.testrw W/System.err:     at
> com.example.testrw.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)

where line 47 is the one I mentioned:

> FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

This "run" shows a problem, but I don't see which one.

Please help me.

Cordially.

Pierre.

Comment: An Android 10 device?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047469/android-read-external-storage-permission-request-question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043494/unable-to-write-to-android-removable-storage-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage). But I only access to the /storage/emulated/0. I have no access to my SD card.

Cordially.

Pierre.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to only reproduce in Galaxy A 41. Did you find the root cause of this error?